# MinIO for Windows local network

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

may I ask what would be the best solution for using [MinIO](https://min.io/) to imitate a local S3 storage for a few Windows nodes?

I have researched some articles and reviewed the MinIO documentation, but I am still struggling.

Is it possible if I host a web server connecting with MinIO in Windows, other Windows nodes may send requests to this server in exchange for the data response?